# swiftで多次元配列が思ったような動作をしてくれません

Tags: swift, xcode

初めまして

```
var a = [String]()

a.insert("a", atIndex: 0)
a.append("b")
a += ["c"]
```

というようなことを、
多重配列したいのですが、

```
var b = [[String]]()

a[0].insert("a", atIndex: 0)
a[1].append("b")
a[2] += ["c"]
```

コンパイルは通るのですが、
この部分で以下のエラーがでます。

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

playgroundで試してもエラーにはなりませんが動作しません。

多次元配列に関する記述があまりみあたりませんのでこちらで質問してみました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

多次元配列の中身が初期化されていません。

```
var b:[[String]] = [[], [], []]

b[0].insert("a", atIndex: 0)
b[1].append("b")
b[2] = ["c"]
```

Answer (score -1):

どうも、Xcode 6.3のPlaygroundでは、配列のメンバーは、Immutableであるようです。バグなのかなんなのかわかりませんが、Playground以外の環境と、挙動が異なりますので、注意が必要です。

二次元配列の初期化は、このようにするといいでしょう。

```
var stringArray = [[String]]()
stringArray.append([String]())
stringArray.insert([String](), atIndex: 1)
stringArray += [["c"]]

stringArray[0].append("a")
stringArray[1].insert("b", atIndex: 0)
stringArray[2] += ["d"]

println(stringArray.description)
```

出力：

> [[a], [b], [c, d]]

Comment: `strArray[0] += "d" // こういう文字列の追加ができない。` ←この行、まったく問題なく実行でき、結果も `[ad, b, c]` が得られましたよ。試した環境はXcode 6.3.1, iOS 8.3, iPhone 6 Plusです。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi コメントありがとうございます。Xcode 6.3のPlaygroundでテストしたところ、**配列のメンバーがImmutableになる**ので、それを鵜呑みにしてました。ビルドして動かす環境（つまりPlayground以外）では、ちゃんとMutableになることを確認しました。それを踏まえて、回答本文を書き換えています。ご了解ください。

Comment: なるほどー、と思ってPlaygroundにそのままコピー＆ペーストしてみましたが、同様に動きましたね。。。私の環境と何か違いがあるのかもしれませんね。